# Execute methods sequence - React

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have written following code to get current user group **Ids** and later from that **Ids** I wanted to filter data from SharePoint list. First I want to execute

> ServiceManager.getRemoteService().getCurrentUserGroups()

method. Once I get group **Ids**, I want to execute the next method. But unfortunately filter part of the REST query is blank because

> this.groupIdString

is blank. This may be because both methods are executed same time. I'm new to React and I want to know is there any best approach to manage this scenario. Basically I want to execute the methods in the order I write.

```
public componentDidMount() {
    this.groupIdString= "";
    ServiceManager.getRemoteService().getCurrentUserGroups(this.props.siteUrl, "/_api/web/currentuser/groups").then((value) => {
                if (value[0]) {
                  for (let i: number = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                     if(value[i].Id != undefined){
                      this.groupIdString += "(UserGroupsId eq " + value[i].Id.toString()+")"; 
                     }
                  }
                }
              });
    const restQuery = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Weather')/Items?$select=Title,NewsBody,UserGroupsId&$filter=("+this.groupIdString+")";

    ServiceManager.getRemoteService().getWeatherListItems(this.props.siteUrl, restQuery).then((value) => {
                if (value[0]) {
                    //code
                }
              });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sivakumar Piratheeban,

You can put the second request in the callback of the first call.

```
public componentDidMount() {
  this.groupIdString = "";
  ServiceManager.getRemoteService().getCurrentUserGroups(this.props.siteUrl, "/_api/web/currentuser/groups").then((value) => {
    if (value[0]) {
      for (let i: number = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if (value[i].Id != undefined) {
          this.groupIdString += "(UserGroupsId eq " + value[i].Id.toString() + ")";
        }
      }

      // Second 
      const restQuery = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Weather')/Items?$select=Title,NewsBody,UserGroupsId&$filter=(" + this.groupIdString + ")";

      ServiceManager.getRemoteService().getWeatherListItems(this.props.siteUrl, restQuery).then((value) => {
        if (value[0]) {
          //code
        }
      });

      //
      
    }
  });

}
```

BR